How to have GitHub Copilot place suggestion in same window in Visual Studio 2022
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.11.6
I am working in VS2022 and open GitHub Copilot chat inline and ask it to add code, docs, etc. When it provides the results, it always opens the results in a new "miscellaneous file" window.
Working in existing class with a function name Add
Ask Copilot to document the method:

The results open in a new file/window:

If I choose to accept the suggestion, it prompts to save a new file (since it did not make the change in my actual file).
If I go back to the existing file/window, the copilot chat window is still there w/ no results.

I would like the results to show up in the file in which I am working, not a new window.
All examples/videos I see demonstrating this feature has the result inline in the same window. I am unable to find any information on how to fix this behavior.
Example of expected behavior from a demo video:


I used the same VisualStudio.17.Release/17.11.6+35431.28, built-in GitHub Copilot   0.2.1671.27212 but did not get your weird situation. You may try refresh your credential....

I refreshed my creds today and am still getting the same result: all copilot chat results are being placed into a new file.

I have no idea then, you may try in other computer and see if the same, hate to say it but sometime reinstall VS may work :\

I experience the same behavior described by M.Ob.
